# Why does my function return 'undefiend' along with the value assigned to the varibale when it is previously declared?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, undefined

```js
// reverse the word
function wordReverse (input) {

    // create variable to store new value
    let newString = "";
    // split string into array of seperate letters
    let splitString = input.split('');
    // run through word backwards and add array values to newString
    for (let i = splitString.length; i >= 0; i--) {

        newString += splitString[i];

    }
// cannot get this not to return 'undefined'
    return newString;

}

const test = wordReverse("word");
console.log(test);
```

Trying to get the word 'word' reversed, but returns:

'undefineddrow'

Tried declaring it with a value, delcaring it outside the function, etc but can't make it work.

Comment: Your first `i` will be `splitString.length`, which is 1 higher than the index of the last element of your array.

Comment: Easy as that, wow. Thank you so much.

Comment: simple console.log statements would have made this clear. `console.log(i, splitString[i]); newString += splitString[i];`

Comment: Will bare in mind in future, cheers

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop i should start at splitString.length - 1

```
for (let i = splitString.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newString += splitString[i];
}
```